# Should we allow school/college-related questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Since we [seem to be allowing non-IT questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/are-non-it-workplace-questions-on-topic), I was wondering if we should also allow questions pertaining to students.

After all,  [work-environment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) seems to be a major part of our scope. Schools/colleges are also a sort of work-environment; they have similar problems.

Of course, this may open the flood gates for a whole bunch of rant-y questions by students.

What say?

Comment: I wouldn't say we're "allowing" non-IT questions, they're simply a necessary part of our scope.

Comment: How about questions about *working* at schools or colleges (as a student employee, administrative staff, teacher, professor, etc)?  In principle these should be in scope, but in practice, there are so many differences between academic and corporate workplaces that I think this site may not have sufficient expertise.

Answer (score 9):

The premise of shrouding academia-related "work" questions under the guise of being a *sort-of* "workplace" seems iffy at best. They are different audiences with different goals, different process, different etiquette, and ultimately different solutions. You can't ask an academia question of a professional audience (the experts) and simply expect their answer apply to the different context. It may or may not; you simply don't know. You're asking the wrong audience.

Considering that we already have an [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com) site, I would very strongly suggest keeping the two subjects separate.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll wait a while for the rest of the community to have its say, before accepting, though.

Comment: @Manishearth its been a year now, long enough to see what the rest of the community thinks before accepting now?

Comment: There is a spectrum, so "took place at a university" doesn't make it about academia *qua* academia.  I worked as a technical person at a university (twice), and I had the same kinds of workplace questions and answers that I do now when working for a regular company.  Even when I worked with students (infrequently), I did so in the way I work with users, interns, or contractors now.  There are issues that are specific to academia, but it's a smaller set than "all questions involving academia in some way".

Answer (score 6):

To the extent that the college and work environments are similar, the questions can be phrased to reflect that similarity, and should be allowed then, in my opinion. "How can I best prepare to get the most out of a meeting or lecture?" "What do I do when working on a class team project and someone isn't pulling their weight?" "What skills/courses are most important for job X?"

Questions that are specific to the school/college settings and don't have professional equivalents should be off topic, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the college/university related questions might be more appropriate for the [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) site. That being said, quite a few questions like "what major should I study" or "where should I go to college" seem to be off-topic for every site - and this one won't be any different.

Comment: I was more of talking about [tag:work-environment]-type questions (also [tag:colleague]), not on choosing stuff. Like "how should I deal with a bully", etc. [This question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-can-i-ask-for-more-positive-reinforcement) applies to students as well, but the answer would be different.